# Trying to assign Lat and Long coordinates to variables, comes back nil

Tags: swift, core-location

I am trying to assign the value from the function that gets the current location. The print statement prints the lat and long coordinates but the variables come back nil.

I have tried moving this to view will appear but still the same results.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        currentLat = locValue.latitude
        currentLong = locValue.longitude
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
    //getWeather()
    }
```

Comment: Where are variables declared? (I assume that by `the variables` you mean `currentLat` and `currentLong`)

Comment: Global variables at the top of the class

var currentLat : Double!
var currentLong : Double!

Comment: Are you sure that your delegate method is _defined_ in `viewDidLoad`? Also, _when_ do you try to access your variables (because they will be non-nil only after the delegate method has been called _and_ the manager's location is non-nil)?

Comment: Yes the delegate is set, in viewDidLoad. I try to access the variables after the locationManager function is ran on view did load

Comment: Marginally unrelated: Don't store separate `lats`/`longs`. Just use `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, that's literally what it's for.

Comment: On your code snippet it seems that the `CLLocationManager` delegate methods is inside the `viewDidLoad` method. Is that correct? If so, try moving it out. Also is the delegate being called at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this function to another view controller in the application because it was not setting the coordinates in time when my original view would load.

I also used:

```
locations.last?.coordinate.longitude
```

As opposed to:

```
guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        currentLong = locValue.longitude
```

Im sure there is a better way to do this but this works.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLong = locations.last?.coordinate.longitude
        currentLat = locations.last?.coordinate.latitude
        print("locations = \(currentLong!) \(currentLat!)")
    }
```